# How to get Customer object's customerID from metadata in Stripe Payment Intent

Tags: api, go, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe payment intent API in golang.
Is there any way I can get customerID from metadata inside of the Customer object?

For example, I create new customer object and insert uuid as metadata. This uuid comes from my database.

```
    // create new customer object
    customerParams := &stripe.CustomerParams{
        Description: stripe.String("Go Stripe Developer"),
        Email:       stripe.String("gostripe@stripe.com"),
        Phone:       stripe.String("1111111111"),
    }
    customerParams.AddMetadata("uuid", "123")
```

I do this because in case something happens to my database and customerID is gone, I can retrieve the data such as purchase history from UUID if I can access to metadata inside of the Customer object.
Or at least, I want to set Customer parameter `deleted: true`, but if there is no customerID record in my database, I cannnot access to the stripe's Customer object since the object can be accessible only from `customerID` itself according to API docs.

Since I noticed I can insert metadata, if there is some way I can access to Customer object using that metadata, that would save my life.
Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution: you can use the List Customers API by `email` and do an additional filter match with `uuid` from metadata (in your code), so you can retrieve the customer detail.